# QMake: Use string as variable

Tags: qt, qmake, build-system

I have a string and I want to use it as part of another variable name

```
QT_MODULE_NAME = xml

# I would like to use something like this:
LIB_PATH = $${QT.$${QT_MODULE_NAME}.libs}
```

But it does not seem to work. I get `Missing } terminator [found $]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
QT_MODULE_NAME = xml
LIB_PATH = $$eval("QT.$${QT_MODULE_NAME}.libs")
message($$LIB_PATH)
```

output:

> Project MESSAGE: /home/pedro/Qt/5.12.7/gcc_64/lib

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted